# How To Pick Random Sound From Array? (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, audio

Looked but could not find an answer to my specific problem.

**What I want to do:**

Call this function from my HTML or in another JS function and play a random sound selected from an array in my JS.

**Playing just one sound using slightly different code works**

I can just play one sound easily enough, my code works in that sense, but I get this error in the console when trying to play multiple sounds with the below code:

> audio.js:90 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call'
>   of undefined

**My code doesn't work, how to fix it?**

Here is my code so far:

```
var SoundRandom = function (soundNameRandom) {
this.soundNameRandom = soundNameRandom;
}

SoundRandom.prototype.playRandomSound = function() {
RandomSound = new Audio(this.soundNameRandom);
var randomSound = Math.random() * 10;
if (randomSound > 5 && isMuted == false) {
  RandomSound[0].play();
 }
 else if (randomSound < 6 && isMuted == false) {
  RandomSound[1].play();
 }
}

var randomSound = new SoundRandom(["sword.mp3", "openinvy.mp3"]);
```

I called it using

> randomSound.playRandomSound();

**My Question**

What is wrong with my code? What did I do wrong or what should I change? Is what I want to do possible with just Javascript? I'd rather not use Jquery. I'm relatively new to the audio side of Javascript so there may be something I'm unaware of.

Also, I don't want to use the HTML audio tag, I want to keep everything in JS, which as I stated earlier DOES work for single sound clips but not a random sound like I'm trying to do.

Comment: This is invalid syntax: `var randomSound = new SoundRandom["sword.mp3", "openinvy.mp3"];`, should be `var randomSound = new SoundRandom(["sword.mp3", "openinvy.mp3"]);`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but the audio still won't play. I am still getting the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined" but no longer the other error.

Comment: I understand that it's probably something wrong with my defining of the variable, but as I said I don't know how to do it otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SoundRandom.prototype.playRandomSound = function() {
var randomSound = Math.random() * 10;
if (randomSound > 5 && isMuted == false) {
  RandomSound = new Audio(this.soundNameRandom[0]);
  RandomSound.play();
 }
 else if (randomSound < 6 && isMuted == false) {
  RandomSound = new Audio(this.soundNameRandom[1]);
  RandomSound.play();
 }
}
```

I do not know if this will work. However, a `Audio` element must be a string, but instead you are putting in an array in the `new Audio()`. The goal of my code was to first get the random integer, then making a new audio based on the names given in the array and play that element.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few errors here: `RandomSound` is not an array, it is an Audio object. I think you are wanting to pick a random song from whatever is passed to `SoundRandom`. To do this, you need to generate a random number between 0 and the length of the array passed to the `SoundRandom` constructor, create the `Audio` object with the file at your random index. This would look more like this (haven't tested it):

```
var SoundRandom = function (sounds) {
  this.sounds = sounds;
}

SoundRandom.prototype.playRandomSound = function() {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.sounds.length);
  var randomSound = new Audio(this.sounds[randomIndex]);

  // play random sound
  if (isMuted === false) {
    randomSound.play();
  }
}

var soundRandom = new SoundRandom(["sword.mp3", "openinvy.mp3"]);
soundRandom.playRandomSound();
```